# Dynamically generated LinkedIn share button in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, linkedin-api

Before I start I should mention that I recently posted a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64923081/using-twitter-widgets-with-html-anchor-a-tag-rendered-by-javascript) where I was trying to do the same with Twitter. I ended up using the twttr.widgets.createShareButton function which worked very cleanly. There may be a similar solution to this issue but I haven't yet been able to find something like that from reading the Microsoft [LinkedIn share-plugin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/plugins/share-plugin) guide.

I am using details and summary tags to show a list of professions with data-elements in each summary storing a code that is appended to the URL of a website. When the user clicks on a summary element it creates a hyperlink to the page with functional skills listing for that role.
I then want to generate a button so the website user can share to LinkedIn.

Here is my [codepen](https://codepen.io/j354374/pen/xxOoqyP) with what I have so far. I have put the code to generate the LinkedIn share button in a function called lnShare.
The line below doesn't seem to be working.

> document.getElementById("p3").appendChild(ln)

I tried returning ln from the lnShare function then calling the appendChild directly after calling the function but that doesn't work either. I am getting:

> ReferenceError: ln is not defined

To better illustrate what I am trying to do this [codepen](https://codepen.io/j354374/pen/dyXBvYV) shows it working with the Twitter twttr.widgets.createShareButton function.

Here is my code:

```js
function lnShare() {
console.log("lnShare started");
const ln = document.createElement('script');
ln.id="LN";
ln.type="IN/Share";
ln.setAttribute("data-url", fs.href);
//document.getElementById("p3").appendChild(ln);
console.log(ln);
return ln;  
 }

const root = "https://www.onetonline.org/link/summary/";



const fs = document.createElement('a');
fs.id="FS";
const linkText = document.createTextNode("functional skills");
fs.appendChild(linkText);
fs.classList.add("hide");
fs.title = "functional skills";
fs.href = "https://www.onetonline.org/link/summary/";

document.getElementById("p1").appendChild(fs);


document.getElementById("container").addEventListener("click",function(e) {
  const tgt = e.target;
  const isSummary = tgt.tagName==="SUMMARY";
  const code = tgt.dataset.code;
  console.log(root+code);
  fs.classList.toggle("hide",!isSummary || !code); // show only if summary AND code exists
  if (isSummary && code) {
    fs.href=root+code;
    console.log(fs.href);
    lnShare(fs.href);
    document.getElementById("p3").appendChild(ln);
  }  
})
```

```css
.hide { display:none; }
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <details id="agriculture" class="details">
    <summary>Agriculture</summary>
    <details>
      <summary data-code="53-7064.00">Picking & packing</summary>
    </details>
    <details>
      <summary data-code="45-2092.02">Farm worker</summary>
    </details>

    <details>
      <summary data-code="45-2091.00">Agricultural Equipment Operator</summary>
    </details>
    <details>
      <summary data-code="45-2093.00">Farmworkers, Farm, Ranch, and Aquacultural Animals</summary>
    </details>

  </details>

  <details id="construction" class="details">
    <summary>Construction</summary>
    <details>
      <summary data-code="47-2061.00">Construction Labourer</summary>
    </details>
    <details>
      <summary data-code="47-2073.00">Operating Engineers and Other Construction Equipment Operators</summary>
    </details>
    <details data-code="47-2051.00">
      <summary>Cement Masons and Concrete Finishers</summary>
    </details>
    <details>
      <summary data-code="47-2021.00">Brickmasons and Blockmasons</summary>
    </details>
    <details>
      <summary data-code="47-4031.00">Fence Erector</summary>
    </details>
    <details>
      <summary data-code="17-3031.01">Surveying Technician</summary>
    </details>
  </details>
</div>

<p id="p1"></p>

<p id="p2"></p>
<p id="p3"></p>
  

  <script src="https://platform.linkedin.com/in.js" type="text/javascript">lang: en_US</script>
```

All assistance is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're referencing `ln` in `document.getElementById("p3").appendChild(ln);`, but that variable has not been initialized. You need to update the previous line to `const ln = lnShare(fs.href);`

Comment: That gets rid of the error message but I see don't see the LinkedIn button which should appear inside <p id="p3"></p>

codepen is here: https://codepen.io/j354374/pen/KKMjmVa

Comment: Well you're appending a script to `p3`, not a button, so it makes sense that there would be no button showing up

Comment: That is true. I might have to make the button (which has id "LN" ) first then append to it but first I was trying to write the script that produces the button in one go. It is the funny way LinkedIn does this.

Comment: Oh, super easy, just add `IN.parse()` after you append `ln`. It appears that in order to load the dynamically generated share buttons, you need to tell the LinkedIn script to reload the share links. h/t https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10178996/how-to-dynamically-load-linkedin-share-button

Comment: Putting script inside p tags is invalid HTML so I am going to look at that too.

Answer (score 1):

The first problem is that `ln` is not in scope in the line `document.getElementById("p3").appendChild(ln)` you can try using `document.getElementById("p3").appendChild(lnShare())`

Comment: Would it need to be this? document.getElementById("p3").appendChild(lnShare(fs.href))

Comment: did it work ? i think you found your solution in the answer above. have fun developing

Comment: I didn't end up using that suggestion however in my project I had to change the lnShare function to use fs instead of fs.href which works on the codepen.
 ln.setAttribute("data-url", fs); //changed from fs.href to just fs to get working